# add correct sign, decimal point and convert to float from two char in a buffer

Tags: c

Im reading a buffer and one char in the buffer represents the number before the decimal and char represent the number after the decimal. I need to concat these, add the decimal, then do 2s compliment to get the correct sign. lastly represent the number (i.e -34.05) as a float.

I have tried to copy the two hex chars out of the buffer so I can work with them.
convert it to binary
use one's, then two's complement to get the sign
use strtoul to get binary back to int
convert the int to decimal (here im not getting the correct value)
if I did get the correct value I would do the same for the other char then concat them and convert to float.
This is a very long process and im hoping to get a better solution.

I cant seem to get from  twos compliment back to int back to dec

```
              Serial.printf("bin:%s\n",bin); // prints out the bin no for testing


            for(i=0; i<binary_size; i++)
                {
                    if(bin[i] == '1')
                    {
                        onesComp[i] = '0'; // invert
                    }
                    else if(bin[i] == '0')
                    {
                        onesComp[i] = '1'; // invert
                    }
                }
                onesComp[binary_size] = '\0'; // add terminating 0

            // convert to 2's comp for correct sign
                for(i=binary_size-1; i>=0; i--)
                {
                    if(onesComp[i] == '1' && carry == 1)
                    {
                        twosComp[i] = '0';
                    }
                    else if(onesComp[i] == '0' && carry == 1)
                    {
                        twosComp[i] = '1';
                        carry = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        twosComp[i] = onesComp[i];
                    }
                }
                twosComp[binary_size] = '\0';     //dont put a terminating 0

                    Serial.printf("\nones:%s   ",onesComp); // prints out the onesComp  for testing
                    Serial.printf("\ntwos:%s   ",twosComp); // prints out the twosComp  for testing


            char * pEnd;
            signed  int int_out;
            int_out = strtoul (twosComp, &pEnd, 8);
            Serial.printf (" twos_comp_int : %d.\n", int_out);

                    decimal = convert(int_out); // convert back to decimal
                    Serial.printf (" decimal : %d.\n", decimal);
            }



            // Convert binary to decimal number pass an argument Bin and returns int Dec
            int convert(int bin_to_dec)
            {
                int rem, i=0, dec=0;

                while(bin_to_dec!=0)
                {
                    rem = bin_to_dec%10;
                    dec += (rem*pow(2,i));
                    bin_to_dec/=10; //bin=bin/10;
                    i++;
                }

                return dec;
            }
```

from an input 
         buf[14]=e5;
         buf[15]=01;

I need a result float = -27.01

Comment: Anything wrong with `printf("%d.%02d", buf[14], buf[15])` ? `Serial.printf` I guess this isn't C. `do 2s compliment to get the correct sign` - I don't understand this. If the second byte stores the number after the decimal point, can it also be negative? Can it be greater then 100? Why and how is 2s complement related in this? If you have received the bytes, why do you care about how the bits are stored? Is your target machine not twos complement?

Comment: In your code, what is the definition of `bin` `dec` `twosComp`, `binary_Size` `onecComp`? You seem to be working with null terminated strings, why are you working with null terminated strings at all? `Convert binary to decimal number` - how can you store a "decimal number" or "binary number" in an `int` and what does that mean? Isn't it _the same number_ that is stored differently? How do you store a number in "decimal" in an `int`?

Comment: If you actually want a float variable in memory at the end of the process, then I can see the quick prinf fix is probably not going to work. You could try creating an integer number that is 100 times too big, convert that to float, then divide by 100 to get the float value you actually want?

Comment: I don't see how you get `-31` from `0xE5` which would be `-27`.

Comment: Binary size is 8 and all the rest required to do ones and two converion
char binary[binary_size + 1];
char onesComp[binary_size + 1];
char twosComp[binary_size + 1];
int carry=1;

Comment: I need to upload the end result to a webserver, the reason im trying to convert between all the number systems is to get form th e two hex chars to  the  signed float with a decimal point. Hence the question there must be an easier way

Comment: Have you tried the function: `strtod()` from the header file:  `stdlib.h`?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me in the end

```
signed char i = 0xFF;
 signed char twosCompliment = ((i<<8) | buf_copy[14]); // get 2s compliment for negative value
sprintf(saveTemperatureBeaconTemperature, "%d.%d" , twosCompliment,buf_copy[15]);
```